# How can I convert a fsa_nt file to FASTA?

Tags: bioinformatics, fasta, genome, sequencing

Im trying to convert a file downloaded from NCBI containing contigs of a bacterial genome. For further analysis I need to have it in FASta format.

I tried converting via seqkit, but it does not work.

Comment: Please explain what exactly did not work. How did you try to use seqkit? How did you determine that it does not work?

Answer (score 1):

`.fsa_nt` extension means that the file is already in the FASTA format. NCBI [GenBank release notes](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genbank/release/134/) describe `.fsa_nt` files as "Nucleotide FASTA".

Typical files downloaded from NCBI have `.fsa_nt.gz` extension. These files are already in FASTA format, compressed in gzip. You can decompress them with `gunzip` or `zcat`.

For example, in *nix system you can do this to download and decompress an `.fsa_nt.gz` file:

```bash
curl ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/wgs_aux/LN/TK/LNTK01/LNTK01.1.fsa_nt.gz | gunzip > LNTK01.1.fasta
```